# Im making a website where anyone can upload image to my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I was following a guide since im new to php and i mostly code Html and Css. Im having problem getting the picture uploaded to the server. Here is the code and a picture after that i've uploaded the picture.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>upload image</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File:
      <input type="file" name="image"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
  <?php
  //connect to database
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("bildproh") or die (mysql_error());


    if (!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
    {
            echo 'No upload';
    }
  // Your file has been uploaded
  else
  {
      $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES ['image']['tmp_name']));
      $image_name = addslashes($_FILES ['image'] ['name']);
      $image_size = getimagesize ($_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name']);

      if($image_size==FALSE)  
        echo "Thats not an image.";
      else
      {
            if  (!$insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO bildproh VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')"))
            echo "Problem uploading image.";    
          else
          {
          $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
          echo "Image upload. <p> your image: </p><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
        }
      }
  }?>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my **get.php**

```
<?php

[This pic is what shows after i have tried to upload the image.][1]

//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("bildproh") or die (mysql_error());

$id = addslashes$_REQUEST ['id'];

$image = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM bildproh WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fletch_assoc($image);
$image = $image ['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;
?>
```

**Image**

[image]

(New code)

```
<html>
<head>


    <title>upload image</title>

    </head>
<body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
        <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>

    <?php

    //connect to database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("bildproh") or die (mysql_error());


if(!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo 'No upload';
}

    // Your file has been uploaded

    else{
        $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES ['image']                 ['tmp_name']));
        $image_name = addslashes($_FILES ['image'] ['name']);
        $image_size = getimagesize ($_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name']);

        if($image_size==FALSE)  
        echo "Thats not an image.";

    }
        else{

    if  (!$insert = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO bildproh VALUES ('','" . $image_name . "','" . $image . "')")
        echo "Problem uploading image.";    


        else{

            $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
            echo "Image upload. <p> your image: </p><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";




        }

         {

         }

    }


    ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How have you tested the code? You have to check for errors, man. BTW, in your `get.php` there is a typo: you have to add brackets after `addslashes`: `addslashes( $_REQUEST ['id'] )`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in you query. To concatenate strings in php you have to use `.`. So you have to change

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO bildproh VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')")
```

to

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO bildproh VALUES ('','" . $image_name . "','" . $image . "')")
```

Also you should stop using `mysql_*` functions and start using the Object oriented style of mysqli.

Comment: The original query is totally correct. With double quotes variables in the strings will be evaluated.

Comment: What is the `echo` message you see after upload an image?

Comment: After using your code i get this ;


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\robert\upload.php on line 40

Comment: You are missing something (`;`, `(`, `)`, `if`, ...). Check your code and test again.

Comment: Can't find where im missing something.

Comment: Could you update the post with the last version of your code?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. As you said before, your query was correct, so I guess the image was being successfully inserted into the database. So the error was when you try to show back the image. I think you were viewing something weird instead the image. That's because the `echo "Image upload. <p> your image: </p><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";`. The `src` attribute is the image url, not the image itself. If you redirect to that url (`get.php?id=$lastid`) you will see the image.

Comment: The reason you have the `unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)` is because you forgot a `)` in the `if`. Also, you have an extra `{` and `}`. Finally, see my last comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220304/im-making-a-website-where-anyone-can-upload-image-to-my-website/35220592?noredirect=1#comment58159974_35220592) and redirect to `get.php?id=$lastid` when a successful image upload.